# not equals in java

Tags: java, arrays, equals, equality

I have this input " 4+4-(4+4+(4+4)))" in an array of strings "balance array"

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
String expression = "";
for(int j=2 ; j<balance.length-1 ; j++)
{
     if(!(balance[j].equals("+")) || !(balance[j].equals("-")) || !(balance[j].equals("(")) || !(balance[j].equals(")")))
          expression = expression + balance[j];
}
```

At the end of the code, expression is supposed to contain "444444", but it is not working.

Am I using the !.equals thing & the || thing in a wrong manner?

I want to combine those 4 statements together using || between them.

Comment: What's the exact type and contents of the `balance` array then? If you're iterating over it it shouldn't be just the one string you mention. Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: why are you starting from 2nd index??

Comment: You should use [regex](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) instead of this - pattern matching will be easier to understand and modify.

Comment: LOL "the || thing"  It's a logical OR operator.  && is the logical AND operator.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR - Or ending at `j < balance.length - 1`?  And a regex searching for digits is probably closer to what you're looking for here anyways... Oh, string concatenation like this often kills performance - you should be using a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), then call `toString()` once you're done (if the regex you come up with doesn't remove the extra characters itself)'.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse i am not OP. i just left a comment :),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
if(!((balance[j].equals("+")) || (balance[j].equals("-")) || (balance[j].equals("(")) || (balance[j].equals(")"))))
```

and

```
for(int j=0 ; j<=balance.length-1 ; j++)
```

Comment: dude, i didn't use j=0 since it have a space as a string
i didn't use j=1 since it have the ( which i want to remove it..
so i preferred j=2.. got i ?
the first code u posted looks more natural, and seems to work as I want.. I will check it then I post an answer
thanks

Answer (score 7):

Change all the `||` to `&&`:

```
     if (!balance[j].equals("+") && !balance[j].equals("-") &&
         !balance[j].equals("(") && !balance[j].equals(")"))
```

Also, both the starting value of `j` and the loop's terminal condition look iffy.